# Firestore query crash on orderBy?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am use Flutter Firebase SDK. When I use this compound query it cause error:

```
      .where('field', whereNotIn: [‘data’])
      .where('otherfield}',
          isEqualTo: anotherField),
     .orderBy(‘timestamp’, descending: false),
```

> An error occurred while parsing query arguments, this is most likely
> an error with this SDK. (

If I remove orderBy, there is no crash.
For example:

```
          .where('field', whereNotIn: [‘data’])
          .where('otherfield}',
              isEqualTo: anotherField),
  //       .orderBy(‘timestamp’, descending: false),
```

Works ^

Why?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you put the `.orderBy(...)` **before** the `.where(...)` calls?

Comment: Not sure if these are deliberate but there are some typos in your code. 'otherfield}' and the comma/dot chain after isEqualTo: anotherField) is invalid.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for reply! Why I must put orderBy before?

Comment: Did you try it? Did it make a difference?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for reply! Yes I try but still crash - same issue

Answer (score 3):

If you include a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field
Valid:

```
citiesRef.where("population", ">", 100000).orderBy("population")
```

Invalid:

```
citiesRef.where("population", ">", 100000).orderBy("country")
```

An example of a bug I have just successfully fixed
Wrong:

```
.whereEqualTo("restaurantID", resRef)
.whereNotEqualTo("image", "")
.orderBy("createdAt", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
```

Right:

```
.whereEqualTo("restaurantID", resRef)
.whereNotEqualTo("image", "")
**.orderBy("image", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)**
.orderBy("createdAt", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).get()
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Answer (score 1):

This is more likely because you haven't created a compound index for this specific request
In the error you will see a url which will lead you to create the compound index and this query will work

Comment: Thanks for reply! But it crash before give link

Comment: Try calling the query in a try {} catch (e) {
 print(e);
}
this will show the error before crashing

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? What does the data look like?  you are ordering By a ‘timestamp’. It might be worth checking the datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Try to creating a Firestore index. [FireStore official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) like this or,

see your console when the app was crashed and there is a link. open that link and create an index.

Comment: Thanks for reply! But it crash before give link